# Databind to refresh only a control, not a whole page

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, refresh

It appears that calling `Control.DataBind()` in C#/ASP refreshes the whole page, and brings the user back to the top of the page.

Is there a way to call `DataBind()` and have it only refresh the control it's affecting, leaving the user at the same spot on the page after the databind?

Comment: One wonders about the context of the `Control.DataBind()` is it happening during a post back? If it is won't that be the cause of the refresh and losing the scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the control within an Update Panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>    
        <control goes here>
    </ContentTemplate>    
</updatePanel>
```